# z-index fails when two elements have a fixed position

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, fixed

I have two fixed elements (a Chat Box and the Cookies Ad) that doesn't position properly even if i add a `z-index`

The Styles

**Chat:**

```
bottom: 0;
position: fixed !important;
right: 40px;
z-index: 9998;
```

**Cookies:**

```
background: #000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
bottom: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #ffffff;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
left: 0;
line-height: 1.3em;
opacity: 0.5;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
```

For more details, you can find it on this page: 
http://www.backlabel.com/

*The HTML is too long to past and copy there..*

Comment: Did you try to set the parent element as `relative` positioned ?

Comment: Sorry, i want to display first the cookies, than you close it and the chat still there.

Comment: @fruitjs im guessing he wants to make them positioned one on top the other

Comment: those divs are siblings? If they are inside anothers div with others z -index doesn`t matter what value you set, they must be at the same level in the DOM

Comment: You'll want to move those elements into the same containing parent element, e.g: moving `#slide_chat_window` into `#footer .row` will resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you see the exact code by clicking there www.backlabel.com

Comment: I use Prestashop and the cookie and the chat are both modules.. i can't did it beacuse i have different hooks..

Comment: @SashaUeChirico if you want the chat div to be below the cookies notice then simply do so in the DOM itself

Comment: have you set the container z-index to something lower ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the cookies `div` above the chat set the higher `z-index` to `.footer-container` `div`

Comment: Was this the issue! 

Thank you!

Comment: @SashaUeChirico (offtopic) "This was the issue" :) "Was this the issue" is a question ;)

Comment: @Dwza Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

As for z-index the Child element always inherits the z-index from its parent so i thing solution for this you should look in parent elements of those divs.

Answer (score 1):

Z-index work perfectly fine for two child elements having position fixed. 
All you need is to check the hierarchy level of the elements.